# How to get the full name of the .deb package in command output

Tags: command-line, package-management, dpkg

Is there any command which can return the full name of the .deb package in ubuntu system if I provided only the name of the package. I know there is a command which gives the information about the package such as version, architecture, etc, but I need the full name in single output which I can use for further use in my web application.

For example:

```
$ some command Lighttpd
lighttpd_1.4.35-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the .deb package"?

Comment: What do you mean by "full name" do you mean the path like `/usr/bin/Lighttpd`? In that case a `.deb` package can contain many executables with different names and sometimes multiple directories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run below command

```
apt-cache show lighttpd | grep Filename
```

Output looks like below.

```
Filename: pool/universe/l/lighttpd/lighttpd_1.4.35-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Below command will give u only the deb file name without the path. `apt` command can be used instead of `apt-cache`.

```
apt-cache show lighttpd | grep Filename | rev | cut -d'/' -f 1 | rev
```

Output:

```
lighttpd_1.4.35-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: If you think apt-cache is not doing well. Replace the apt-cache with apt. It will still work.

Comment: It worked like a charm this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much worked for me. Great appreciation

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, because there is no direct correlation between an installed debian package, and the filename it was installed from.

You can of course construct the filename you've given an example of, by simply combining the various details about the package which are in the installed packages database, but it is not necessarily an accurate description of the file from which the package came. You could create a script to give you this inaccurate file name in several different languages.

Comment: apt-cache shows it right?

Comment: apt-cache is not so good with installed packaged I guess. And it doesn't give the full .deb package name.

Comment: You can just pipe all of `dpkg -l` output into an awk script really, to do it for the list of all installed packages. Also, I don't think `apt-cache` works for things that are not from an apt repository.